# ssh_config auto restored after some time

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, git, ssh-keys

I need to connect to `git` using an ed25519 SSH key, but the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` only has the entries below for `IdentityFile`, so I receive error `Permission denied (publickey)` when accessing the `git` repo:

```ini
IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

- I added `IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and can access the `git` repo afterwards; however, after an SSH session ends, or after `git` commands start failing, I see `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is restored to default and the entry I added is lost

How do I edit this file and what is the correct way to add an entry for key file `id_ed25519`?

Comment: The [wrong](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) config is being modified, as `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is for system-wide defaults, instead modify `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: @JW0914: ssh_config is not an "ini" file, and OP's original version without the `=` is actually how it looks most of the time.

Comment: @user1686 We've had this conversation before - please review the SSH man pages, such as the third paragraph of the [`ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) man page. This appears to bother you - perhaps you could suggest the `ini` syntax highlighting for Superuser be modified to work without the `=` _(the `=` character is widely used in SSH config files - simply because an individual hasn't come across it often has no bearing)_

Comment: try changing file ~/.ssh/config but this doesn't help and the error ```Permission denied (publickey)``` while accessing git repo is continue, this error is only resolved if I change in ```/etc/ssh/ssh_config```

Comment: @MUKHTARINAMDAR Something is misconfigured then, as `~/.ssh/config` always takes [precedence](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) over the global config [`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`]. Please post both configs. _(When replying to comments, please mention the user [e.g. `@JW0914`], else no one's notified of a comment reply.)_

Answer (score -2):

This happens because DSA keys are not secure anymore, so add to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```ini
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes = +ssh-dss
```

Comment: Not only should this not be added to the system-wide config _(it should be added to the user's config: [`~/.ssh/config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config))_, an SSH config should not be made insecure when the option added has nothing to do with ed25519 keys